# Querying Big Query tables with multiple repeated records

Tags: nested, google-bigquery

I have a table with three repeated record types.

A sample of the table looks like:

```
STR string,
SKU integer,
DAILY_SALES record repeated,
DAILY_SALES.SLS_DT DATE,
DAILY_SALES.SLS_AMT FLOAT,
PROD_HIER record repeated,
PROD_HIER.PROD_DESC STRING,
PROD_HIER.DEPT   integer,
PROD_HIER.EFF_BGN_DT DATE,
STR_HIER record repeated,
STR_HIER.STR_NM string,
STR_HIER.DIV    string,
STR_HIER.EFF_BGN_DT DATE
```

For every STR/SKU record, I need to get data from PROD_HIER which has the maximum (latest) EFF_BGN_DT and also get the record from STR_HIER which has lastest STR_HIER.EFF_BGN_DT.

It would help if this can be done both in legacy sql (for external tools) and standard SQL.  Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> For BigQuery Standard SQL (see [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql))

```
SELECT 
  STR, 
  SKU, 
  (SELECT STRUCT(PROD_DESC, DEPT, EFF_BGN_DT) 
      FROM UNNEST(PROD_HIER) 
      ORDER BY EFF_BGN_DT DESC LIMIT 1
  ) AS PROD_HIER,
  (SELECT STRUCT(STR_NM, EFF_BGN_DT) 
      FROM UNNEST(STR_HIER) 
      ORDER BY EFF_BGN_DT DESC LIMIT 1
  ) AS STR_HIER
FROM YourTable
```

> For BigQuery Legacy SQL

This one has an assumption that your repeated fields have at least one entry each.  If this is not a case  - you should modify slightly JOIN (see more about [JOIN operator and JOIN types](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#joins)

```
SELECT
  PROD_HIER.STR AS STR, 
  PROD_HIER.SKU AS SKU, 
  PROD_HIER.PROD_DESC,
  PROD_HIER.DEPT,
  PROD_HIER.EFF_BGN_DT,
  STR_HIER.STR_NM,
  STR_HIER.EFF_BGN_DT
FROM (
  SELECT 
    STR, 
    SKU, 
    PROD_HIER.PROD_DESC AS PROD_DESC,
    PROD_HIER.DEPT AS DEPT,
    PROD_HIER.EFF_BGN_DT AS EFF_BGN_DT,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY STR, SKU ORDER BY EFF_BGN_DT DESC) AS win
  FROM YourTable
) AS PROD_HIER
JOIN (
  SELECT 
    STR, 
    SKU, 
    STR_HIER.STR_NM AS STR_NM, 
    STR_HIER.EFF_BGN_DT AS EFF_BGN_DT,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY STR, SKU ORDER BY EFF_BGN_DT DESC) AS win
  FROM YourTable
) AS STR_HIER
ON PROD_HIER.STR = STR_HIER.STR
AND PROD_HIER.SKU = STR_HIER.SKU
AND PROD_HIER.win = STR_HIER.win
WHERE PROD_HIER.win = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Curious - can this be done in Legacy SQL.  Currently Tableau and other tools only work with legacy SQL

Comment: Depending on the tool, you may be able to put `#StandardSQL` at the start of your query in order to use standard SQL.

Comment: @DWPro - added version for Legacy SQL. Still - consider option in Elliott's comment